# Failed to initialize SASL authentication: InitializeSecurityContext failed when connecting to Kafka

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, .net-4.8, sasl, confluent-kafka-dotnet

We get the below error when trying to produce to a Confluent Kafka topic. It tries to authenticate for a few minutes and times out. This application (4.8) is hosted on a Windows Server (IIS) and uses a service account to run. The service account has the required Kafka roles to produce to the topic.

Failed to initialize SASL authentication: InitializeSecurityContext failed: (no string representation) (0x80090342) (after 42ms in state AUTH_REQ)

(_AUTHENTICATION): identical to last error: error log suppressed[thrd:sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap: Broker changed state AUTH_REQ -> DOWN[thrd:sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change[thrd:sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers[thrd:sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers[thrd:sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset[thrd:main]: Topic 758-MobileOrders metadata information unknown[thrd:main]: Topic 758-MobileOrders partition count is zero: should refresh metadata[thrd:main]: Cluster connection already in progress: refresh unavailable topics[thrd:main]: Hinted cache of 1/1 topic(s) being queried[thrd:main]: Skipping metadata refresh of 1 topic(s): refresh unavailable topics: no usable brokers[thrd:sasl_ssl://xrcdrckm.hszq.com:6653/bootstrap]: Hinted cache of 1/1 topic(s) being queried[thrd:main]: Not selecting any broker for cluster connection:

We tried the following, but no luck,

- Synchronous and Asynchronous calls
- Checked Firewall and Proxy
- Writing to a different topic
- Verified the permissions
- Running the application from a different server